# VBA macro that can update the worksheets based on a source worksheet cell range

Tags: vba, excel

So what I'm trying to do is to update a list of worksheets based on the cell range in my source worksheet (same workbook). I know I could probably do this by deleting all the worksheets and adding new ones, but I need to have it where it takes out one and adds another.

Here is what I have so far, my problem started with the macros not responding when run or when I try to combine both macros so that I can link it to a button, nothing happens.

```
Sub Delete_Insert()

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim stocks As Variant

Dim c_stocks As Integer
c_stocks = 7
Dim match As Boolean
'This is to see if a worksheet matched with a stock name
Dim j As Integer
j = 1
'To count the internal cell FOR loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'This turns off the alert for deleting sheets

For Each ws In Worksheets

c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    match = False
        For Each stocks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("A2:A8").Cells
            If CStr(stocks) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).name Then
                match = True
                Exit For 
            End If
            Next stocks
    If match = False Then
            ws.Delete
    End If
    i = i + 1
    If i = c Then
            Exit For
    End If
    Next ws
End Sub`
```

And then this is to insert

```
For Each stocks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("A2:A8").Cells
    i = 2
    match = False
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If (ws.name = stocks) Then
                match = True
                Exit For

            End If

        i = i + 1


        Next ws

    If match = False Then

                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                ActiveSheet.Move After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.name = CStr(stocks)
    End If

     j = j + 1

    If (j = 7) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    Next stocks


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```
Sub Delete_Insert()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim stocks As Range, c As Range, stck As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set stocks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("A2:A8")

    'remove sheets not in list
    For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set sht = wb.Worksheets(i)
        If IsError(Application.match(sht.Name, stocks, 0)) Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            sht.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        End If
    Next i

    'add new sheets from list
    For Each c In stocks.Cells
        stck = c.Value
        If Len(stck) > 0 Then

            Set sht = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sht = wb.Worksheets(stck)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If sht Is Nothing Then
                With wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
                    .Name = stck
                End With
            End If

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```